# Is there a lower level programming language between C and assembly?

Tags: c

I may be using vague terms here but trying to understand it.  I have heard the term "closer to the metal" and C is close but other than Binary and Assembly, I am wondering if there is anything between those and C.
I have learned Python, Javascript, C# and some Swift but I am shifting focus to C to help me understand those languages at a deeper level.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: In what way do you think this will help you understand anything better?

Comment: The Linux kernel is programmed mainly in C, with a bit of assembly. So no, you can't really go much "closer to the metal" than C, without going into assembly.

Comment: As you described, _"raw"_ is very broad and vague. C was designed to be portable and as close to the hardware as possible. It is called a portable assembly.

Comment: There is at least one language that is part-way between assembly and C, called HLA ("High Level Assembly"). There may be others I'm unaware of.

Comment: @Cheatah I see how easy Python and JavaScript’s syntax is and I was wondering what was going on at a deeper level or in a more raw formatted programming language.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel That’s what I was reading, I’m glad to get that confirmation from this community.

Comment: `clang` can compile C code to LLVM intermediary language, which is in turn compiled to CPU instructions by `llvm`. In a sense LLVM intermediary language is exactly what you are asking about: *a lower level programming language between C and assembly.*

Comment: This question is not *opinion-based*, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie, that helps clear things up

Comment: @Zakk I’m new to understanding these concepts but that was the best words I could find. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @BenjaminJensen: C is very close to the *metal*: sometimes you can get closer  and touch the actual gritty details using compiler and CPU specific inline assembly.  As documented in the [Jargon File](http://catb.org/jargon/html/C/C.html): C is *a language that combines all the elegance and power of assembly language with all the readability and maintainability of assembly language.* Also check this [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=7327) article: there is a fairly clear answer to your question half way down the page.

Answer (score 1):

The lowest-level language dialects that are in common use are dialects of C.  On the flip side, not all C dialects support low-level concepts particularly well.  Some constructs are in fact supported more reliably in languages like in C# and even Javascript than in some dialects of C.

There have been other languages which even lower-level than low-level dialects of C, but I've never really used them.  I think Forth and PROMOL would probably qualify, and maybe Intel's PL/M.  C has the advantage, however, that if multiple people each want to produce a dialect to support low-level programming on a particular platform, the dialects thus produced are apt to be very similar and largely compatible even without any kind of official standard indicating how they should handle platform-specific features.

Comment: "Some constructs"? Such as?

Comment: @AKX: Constructs which would dynamically interpret parts of a region of storage as 1, 2, 4, and 8 byte signed or unsigned integer chunks, or as 4- or 8-byte double, are supported in Javascript and C#, but the C Standard does not mandate such support, and if one enables optimizations in clang and gcc without explicitly demainding such support, they will not process such constructs reliably.

Comment: @supercat: types in `<stdint.h>` were added exactly for this purpose. The are not mandated because they do not make sense on exotic architectures with non 8-bit bytes or ancient integer representations.  Mandating them on de factor standard architectures with 8-bit bytes, two's complement signed integers and IEEE floating point hardware should indeed be made part of the Standard. By *reliably*, you probably refer to optimisations that may remove memory accesses, `volatile` more or less addresses this problem.

Comment: @supercat: conversely, I do regret not being able to describe precise memory layout for structures: bit-field positions and signedness, integer endianness and width (other than 8,16,32,64), alignment or lack thereof, bit and bit-field arrays... and have the compiler generate whatever emulating code is necessary for the current target.

Comment: @chqrlie: Suppose I have a monochrome bitmap screen and want to draw both 16-pixel-aligned 16x16 and 32-pixel-aligned 32x32 tiles.  Accessing the storage as 32-bit values when drawing 32-bit tiles and 16-bit values when drawing 16-bit tiles will be more efficient than using pairs of 16-bit accesses when drawing 32-bit tiles or read-modify-write sequences when drawing 16-bit tiles.  Not a problem on implementation whose optimizers make any attempt to recognize and accommodate type punning, but there's no way to distinguish implementations where such things will work reliably from...

Comment: ...those that may be broken by compiler optimizations.

Comment: @chqrlie: If the Standard were to say that if storage may only accessed within some context as type `T` and then within that same context as type `U` if there is some particular evidence within that context that would imply a relationship between objects of such types, that would have prevented the absurd controversies surrounding such issues, but unfortunately maintainers of free compilers insist they have no obligation to notice such evidence, no matter how obvious it may be.

Comment: @supercat: as a former graphics programmer, I sympathise with you, having experienced the same headaches. As a compiler writer, I try to keep in mind that optimizations should not produce counter-intuitive behavior. If the Standard allows them to, the Standard should be changed IMHO. At the very least compiler warnings should be issued when it is not obvious that the programmers know what there are doing.

Comment: @chqrlie: The goal of a quality compiler should be to produce behavior which is consistent with that of sequentially executing all steps of a program *in all ways that matter*.  Because different implementations are used for different purposes, optimizations that would be appropriate for some would be inappropriate for others.  The authors of the Standard thus make little effort to mandate support for corner cases that would be useful for some customers but not all, since anyone wishing to sell compilers would support the cases that matter to their customers, with or without a mandate.

Comment: @chqrlie: It's too bad that these issues weren't properly framed 15-20 years ago.  If e.g. Linus Torvalds had said "The fact that the Standard would not forbid a garbage-quality-but-conforming implementation from making code-breaking 'optimizations' ; but compiler writers who make code-breaking optimizations should be recognized as deliberately producing garbage-quality implementations", the language would be in much better shape today.

Answer (score 0):

Short from writing straight up assembly or machine code, no there isn't another language as 'raw' as C

Some alternatives- Zig, rust, and nim - above C - but still close to metal

Comment: That is not strictly true: clang can compile C code to LLVM intermediary language, which is in turn compiled to CPU instructions. In a sense LLVM intermediary language is exactly what the OP is asking about: *a lower level programming language between C and assembly.*

Comment: @chqrlie: Unfortunately, LLVM's abstraction model includes some assumptions which might make sense in some special-purpose high-level languages, but not in a language intended for low-level programming.  Fundamental among those is an assumption that in all cases where it would be acceptable for a program to behave in a manner which is somewhat inconsistent with sequential execution, all possible behaviors by the program would be regarded as equally acceptable.